# Custom InputView for UISearchBar doesn't work in iOS7

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, ios7, inputview

I need to set my custom inputView in UISearchBar.

So i wrote following codes , that is working perfectly in iOS5 and iOS6 .

However it doesn't work in iOS7.

```
for(int i =0; i<[self.searchBar.subviews count]; i++) {
            if([[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                [(UITextField*)[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyCustomFont" size:15]];
                UITextField* search=(UITextField*)[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                search.delegate = self;

                [(UITextField*)[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setInputView:self.customKeyboard];
                [self.customKeyboard setTextView:search];
            }
        }



        [self.sBar reloadInputViews];
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The searchBar sub views hierarchy has been changed in iOS7, try the below:

**iOS7:**

```
NSArray *searchBarSubViews = [[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews];
```

**iOS6** and before:

```
NSArray *searchBarSubViews =  self.searchBar.subviews;
```

Try below updated function:

```
NSArray *searchBarSubViews = [[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews];
for(int i =0; i<[searchBarSubViews count]; i++) {
    if([[searchBarSubViews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField* search=(UITextField*)[searchBarSubViews objectAtIndex:i];
        [search setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyCustomFont" size:15]];
        search.delegate = self;

        [search setInputView:self.customKeyboard];
        [self.customKeyboard setTextView:search];
    }
}
[self.sBar reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: So how can i set InputView with NSArray?

Comment: By changing you if in the second line  if([[ [[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])  and so on for the rest.

Comment: Did you change searchBar.subviews in the whole function?

Comment: thz bro. Now i got it. Cheer!. :D